# How do I solve Access Insert into table error?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I'm doing a project and I just used some code from YouTube where it seemed to work, but it isn't working for me. I am getting this message. :/

```
Run-time Error: '3134':
Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Dodaj_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Rezervacije( JMBG, Grad, Broj dana, Broj osoba) " & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.JMBG & "', '" & Me.Destinacija & "', '" & Me.Dani & "', '" & Me.Osobe & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Putnici(Broj licne karte, Ime, Prezime, JMBG, Mobilni, Email, Pol) " & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.Licna & "', '" & Me.Ime & "', '" & Me.Prezime & "', '" & Me.JMBG & "', '" & Me.Mobilni & "', '" & Me.Email & "', '" & Me.Pol & "')"
End Sub
```

Comment: Columns with spaces must be written as `[Broj osoba]`/`[Broj licne karte]`.  You should rewrite this to be a parameterized insert to avoid SQL Injection problems (Put a `'` in one of the inserted values & see what happens).

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, it seemed to have solved the problem ^.^